# How I can I delay the expansion of a collapsible until its content is fetched?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I want to integrate a collapsible in my jQM app (1.3.2) that works as follows:

1. It starts **collapsed**.
2. On click it starts to fetch listitems for the collapsible from the server. The **collapsible stays closed**, a load icon may be spinning.
3. After all elements are loaded and the listview refreshed and ready, the **collapsible expands**.
4. If you click it again, it **closes directly** without delay, and starts from 1.

My initial idea was to grab the `expand` event and prevent its propagation. When loading is finished I de-register my custom event handler to turn the collapsible back to normal, and finally triggering the expand event from JavaScript to open.

The problem is that this works for the first round, but afterwards the collapsible opens anyway. Consider this example (also in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwil/VG6Gr/)):

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="c">
  <h2>Collapse</h2> 
  <ul data-role="listview" id="lv">
    <li>You don't see me!</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" data-role="button" onClick="$('#c').off('expand', stop)">
  Unlock the collapsible
</a>

<a href="#" data-role="button" onClick="$('#c').on('expand', stop)">
  Lock the collapsible
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var stop = function(event) {
  alert('Locked!');
  event.preventDefault();
}

// executed after the element is created ...
$('#c').on('expand', stop)
```

Here, if you click the collapsible after loading, it stays closed (good). When you click unlock, it opens and no alert is shown (good). If you lock it again it shows the alert (good) but opens anyways (bad).

Can anyone enlighten me what I am doing wrong? There seems to be side-effects from unlocking that I cannot see. There are several similar questions here, but most are happy with just preventing the expansion without turning it back on again.

So my question is: **What is the best way to delay the expansion of a collapsible reliably?**

---

**Edit:** I added another example that integrates the listview logic and also shows this error. [jsFiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mwil/sHaju/) I also moved to `.one()` to make the de-registering more traceable.

New JavaScript:

```
var stop_n_load = function (event) {
  alert('stop opening! (or at least try to ...)');

  // try to stop the expanding by stopping the event
  event.preventDefault();

  // Do some work that takes time and trigger expand afterwards ...
  setTimeout(function (e) {
    dd = new Date();
    $('#lv').empty();
    $('#lv').append("<li><a href='#'>Item A ("+dd+")</a></li>");
    $('#lv').append("<li><a href='#'>Item B ("+dd+")</a></li>");
    $('#lv').listview('refresh');

    // when done, start expanding without this handler (was register only once)
    $('#c').trigger('expand');
    // for the next collapse register stop_n_load again
    $('#c').one('collapse', reset);
  }, 2000);
};

var reset = function (event) {
  $('#c').one('expand', stop_n_load);
};

$('#c').one('expand', stop_n_load);
```

On the first expansion it works as expected, it first updates and then opens. On the second run it opens without waiting, you can see the timestamp updating later, so the event is called properly.

*There seems to be a problem with `.preventDefault()` I don't understand ...*

Comment: you need to use `return false` = `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` together. check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yXa4W/

Comment: Thanks @Omar, this looks great! Why does the click event doesn't have the problem that `.preventDefault()` is still set on the second click? And can you please make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: when collapsible is expanded, `ui-collapsible-collapsed` class is removed so second click works normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `expand`/`collapse` events are triggered, jQM adds several classes to show/hide contents as well as update collapsible button/header.

In this case, [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) isn't going to prevent event(s) from bubbling and stop them from executing. Thus you need to use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) to stop `expand` event once header is clicked.

When a collapsible is collapsed, it has a class `ui-collapsible-collapsed` and once expanded, the class is removed. Therefore, when `collapse` is triggered, it works normally without interruption.

```
$(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").on("click", function (e) {

    // check if collapsible is whether expanded or collapsed
    if ($(this).closest(".ui-collapsible").hasClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")) {

        // true
        // stop "expand" event on click,tap,vclick,touchstart, etc...
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // show loading msg - optional
        $.mobile.loading("show", {
            text: "Loading...Please wait",
            textVisible: true
        });

        // for demo
        // add items, expand and hide loading msg
        setTimeout(function () {                
            $("#lv").empty().append(items).listview("refresh");
            $("#c").trigger("expand");
            $.mobile.loading("hide");
        }, 1000);
    }

    // false
    // collapse normally or do something else
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yXa4W/)**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not intimately familiar with JQM but my first thought was empty the list before sending for more data....which seems to prevent it expanding.

```
var stop = function(event) {    
    $(this).find('.ui-listview').empty()
    event.preventDefault();

    /* do ajax and then refresh component with expand enabled */
}

$('#c').on('expand', stop);
```

[DEMO - without ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/a46rr/11/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this only partially solves my problem because you can still see the collapsible reacting (some empty space below it is added, the icon changes). [I made another fiddle with additional listview logic](http://jsfiddle.net/mwil/nCjLX) with your idea integrated, you should see the problem. There must be a solution to get the events straight, it works as I want on the first click after all ...

Comment: i guess is browser/device depeendednt....am not sseing same as you using my dev browsers FF & Chrome on windows

Answer (score 0):

After wading around in the event system, I concluded for now that if you set `preventDefault()` once you are stuck with it forever. Based on the solution of **charlietfl** I added code to make the visual impact minimal, maybe there is also a way to prevent the GUI from refreshing for the 20ms to make it fully unnoticable.

```
var stop_n_load = function (event) {
  $('#lv').empty();
  $('#lv').listview('refresh');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#c').trigger('collapse');
  }, 20);

  // Do some work that takes time and trigger expand afterwards ...
  setTimeout(function () {
    dd = new Date();
    $('#lv').empty();
    $('#lv').append("<li><a href='#'>Item A (" + dd + ")</a></li>");
    $('#lv').append("<li><a href='#'>Item B (" + dd + ")</a></li>");
    $('#lv').listview('refresh');

    $('#c').trigger('expand');
    $('#c').one('collapse', reset);
  }, 2000);
};
```

I'm still searching for a solution that resets the event to its previous state, though.